# how to set pdf file zoom factor using the pdf.js and jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, pdf.js

My application has a function for displaying pdf receipts. the receipts are generated dynamically. i used the pdf.js plugin for this purpose.

my requirements to set zoom for the pdf page. here is working code for generating pdf file without the zoom factor. but struggled lot for set the zoom factor.

```
pdfData: function() {

        $("#pdfContainer").empty();
        scale = 3.5; //Set this to whatever you want. This is basically the "zoom" factor for the PDF.
        var pdfBase64 = pdfBase64Res;
        currentPage = 1;
        pages = [];

        // Converts a base64 string into a Uint8Array

        function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {

            var base64New = base64.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var raw = atob(base64New); //This is a native function that decodes a base64-encoded string.
            var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(raw.length));
            for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
                uint8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return uint8Array;
        }

        function loadPdf(pdfData) {
            PDFJS.disableWorker = true; //Not using web workers. Not disabling results in an error. This line is
            //missing in the example code for rendering a pdf.
            var pdf = PDFJS.getDocument(pdfData);
            pdf.then(renderPdf);
        }



        function renderPdf(pdf) {
            alert("total page numbers :" + pdf.numPages);
            totalPages = pdf.numPages;
            pdf.getPage(currentPage).then(renderPage);


            function renderPage(page) {
                pagesNew = page;
                height = 768;
                viewport = page.getViewport(1);
                scale = height / viewport.height;
                scaledViewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                //  canvas = document.createElement("<canvas>");
                context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = scaledViewport.height;
                canvas.width = scaledViewport.width;
                // element=document.getElementById("pdfContainer");

                renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: scaledViewport
                };

                pagesNew.render(renderContext).then(function() {
                    if (totalPages == 1) {

                        jQuery("#pdfContainer").append(canvas);

                    } else if (currentPage <= pdf.numPages) {
                        //alert('Current page'+currentPage);
                        pdf.getPage(currentPage).then(renderPage);
                        pages[currentPage] = canvas;
                        console.log(pages[currentPage]);

                        ++currentPage;


                        // alert("before for loop");
                    } else {
                        //alert('in else');

                        //alert("alert(pages.length);"+pages.length);
                        for (var i = 1; i < pages.length; i++) {
                            //alert(i);
                            var element = document.getElementById("pdfContainer");
                            element.appendChild(pages[i]);
                            console.log(element.appendChild(pages[i]));
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        var pdfData = base64ToUint8Array(pdfBase64);
        loadPdf(pdfData);
```

Comment: Can you provide this function to display the pdf so however needs to assist can get more clarity.

Comment: @Lingaraj Sajjan, on an unrelated note, can you provide assistance here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154427/download-pdf-file-from-through-mobilefirst-adapter

Comment: @Idan Adar, i checked your above link but its not related to my exact requirement, i am getting the base64 response from the worklight adapter and i have converted to pdf format then i have to set zoom factor for pdf file this is what am looking please can you assist ?

Comment: No. I asked if you can help the person who asked the other question in the link.