# How to implement a file download with IBM MobileFirst 7.1?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

My app requires to download several files from a http server and store then in the mobile device. The server provides a URL for each file, and REST services for the mobile app get the file names.

I can achive this using simple http GET calls in the mobile app? Or there is some more direct functions, for example, GetFile or another similar thing?

Regards

Comment: It uses the old-style JavaScript adapters, but you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154427/download-pdf-file-from-through-mobilefirst-adapter

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help! Question resolved, the final code:

```
function downloadImages(imageFileName, url) {

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var remoteFilePath = encodeURI(url + imageFileName );

    var localDownloadPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + imageFileName;

    fileTransfer.download(
            remoteFilePath,
            localDownloadPath,

            function(successResponse) {
                $("#log").append("<tr><td>Arquivo " + imageFileName + " baixado.</tr></td>");
                $("#log").append("<tr><td><img src='" + cordova.file.dataDirectory + imageFileName + "' /></tr></td>");
            },

            function(errorResponse) {
                $("#log").append("<tr><td>Erro ao baixar o Arquivo " + imageFileName + ": " + errorResponse.errorMsg + "</tr></td>");
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cordova-provided APIs to accomplish this.
See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030914/ibm-worklight-using-cordova-apache-api-to-handle-files

Comment: Thanks for the faster than light answer, Idan!